# Using bash script to select/view only specific data from logfile

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, format

My NAS creates a logfile in the format below:

```
<30>1 2014-07-21T05:02:10+02:00 ABC-NAS qlogd 6432 - - qlogd[6432]: event log: Users: Glacier, Source IP: 127.0.0.1, Computer name: localhost, Content: [Glacier] Backup job [Backup ABC-PC] finished successfully

<30>1 2014-07-21T05:02:27+02:00 ABC-NAS qlogd 6432 - - qlogd[6432]: event log: Users: Glacier, Source IP: 127.0.0.1, Computer name: localhost, Content: [Glacier] Backup job [Backup ABC-HTPC] finished successfully

<28>1 2014-07-21T05:10:59+02:00 ABC-NAS qlogd 6920 - - qlogd[6920]: event log: Users: Glacier, Source IP: 127.0.0.1, Computer name: localhost, Content: [Glacier] Backup job [Backup ABC-NAS] is abnormal shutdown

<30>1 2014-07-21T06:00:15+02:00 ABC-NAS qlogd 6920 - - qlogd[6920]: event log: Users: Glacier, Source IP: 127.0.0.1, Computer name: localhost, Content: [Glacier] Backup job [Backup ABC Metadata] started

<30>1 2014-07-21T06:00:27+02:00 ABC-NAS qlogd 6920 - - qlogd[6920]: event log: Users: Glacier, Source IP: 127.0.0.1, Computer name: localhost, Content: [Glacier] Backup job [Backup ABC Metadata] finished successfully
```

Using a BASH script I would like to create a textfile only containing:

```
Monday 21 July 2014 - 04:10 AM
Glacier Backup job [Backup ABC-PC] finished successfully

Monday 21 July 2014 - 07:02 AM
Glacier Backup job [Backup ABC-HTPC] finished successfully
```

and so on.

I have been trying with cat and grep, but it soon gets too complicated for me. Who can help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

here is a super simple brute force bash script

```
cat log | cut -d " " -f 2,20- | while read -r date message; do
  echo $date
  echo $message
done
```

sample output

```
2014-07-21T05:02:10+02:00
[Glacier] Backup job [Backup ABC-PC] finished successfully


2014-07-21T05:02:27+02:00
[Glacier] Backup job [Backup ABC-HTPC] finished successfully
```

if you wish for more features then i strongly advice you to learn python.